# Is this problem on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ really hard?

Tags: hardness-assumptions

I just want to know if there's something obvious that renders this hard problem useless. Not a full cryptoanalisys. Any hint on whatever is welcomed.

We will work with the Ring $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, $p$ prime.

Now, we define a function $f:\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p}\mapsto\mathbb{Z}_{p}$,
as $f\left(a,b\right)=\frac{-a\,b+a+b+z}{a+b-1}$, $z\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, $z$ is a public constant value.

Next, we define a series as follows:

$a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_{p},\ s_{0}=a,\ s_{1}=b,\ s_{n}=f\left(s_{n-2},\ s_{n-1}\right)$

And for a given element of the series, $s_{n}$, a value $r_{n}=f\left(s_{n},a\right)$

The question is, taking into account that the function $f$ is not
associative, how difficult is, knowing $b$ and $r_{n}$, recover
the value of a secret $a$. As an example of sizes let's say $n=256,\ p\sim2^{256}$.

This problem leads to a public key cryptosystem described here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OeKh_ZJF-i7_KzWFRv8jodk3YkXe2qyv

Daniel Nager - daniel.nager@gmail.com

Comment: Please clarify: Is $z$ a parameter of the function $f$? Is it a public parameter or a secret parameter?

Comment: It's a constant like $p$. You need to agree on a prime and $z$ before using the cryptosystem. Anyway $z$ can be zero. Let me note that problem's hardness is based on the non-associavity of the function $f$, which disables DLP-like approaches.

Comment: In order for $f$ to be a properly defined function, you have to provide a separate definition for the cases when $a+b=1$. The currently stated formula is undefined for such input.

Comment: "This problem leads to a public key cryptosystem described here:..." There is no description of a cryptosystem. And in the 'signature scheme', there is more information given than what you propose the problem to be here. In general: You might want to find a better argument for security than "I could not find one, and dlog us not applicable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: **No**, that problem is not hard.

Synopsis: After remapping of $\Bbb Z_p$ by an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) $x\to\overline x$, the function $(x,y)\to\overline{-f(\overline x,\overline y)}$ is mostly associative. We massage it into an Abelian finite group $(\mathcal S,\boxplus)$. This makes $\overline{r_n}$ a linear function of $\overline a$ and $\overline b$ with known scalar coefficients, allowing to efficiently solve the question's problem.

---

Define $\delta$ and $\hat z$ in $\Bbb Z_p$ with $\delta=(p+1)/2$ and $\hat z=(-3\,\delta^2-z)\bmod p$. The reason will become apparent later, for now consider $\hat z$ as an arbitrary fixed public element of $\Bbb Z_p$.

Define $l$ as the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) $l=\displaystyle\biggl(\frac{\hat z}p\biggr)$, and define $m=p-l$.

When $l=+1$, define $\omega$ as a particular solution of $\omega^2=a$ in $\Bbb Z_p$, e.g. the odd one in range $[1,p)$.

Define the set $\mathcal S$ as:
$$\mathcal S=\begin{cases}
\{\infty\}\cup\Bbb Z_p&\text{when }l=-1\\
\{\infty\}\cup\Bbb Z_p-\{0\}&\text{when }l=0\\
\{\infty\}\cup\Bbb Z_p-\{\omega,p-\omega\}&\text{when }l=+1
\end{cases}$$

Define internal law $\boxplus$ in $\mathcal S$ as:
$$x\boxplus y=\begin{cases}
y&\text{when }x=\infty\\
x&\text{when }x\ne\infty\text{ and }y=\infty\\
\infty&\text{when }x\ne\infty\text{ and }y=-x\\
(x+y)^{-1}(x\,y+\hat z)&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$(\mathcal S,\boxplus)$ is¹<sup>,</sup>²<sup>,</sup>⁶ a finite [Abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) of $m$ elements with neutral $\infty$. With the convention $-\infty=\infty$, the opposite $-x$ of $x$ in group $(\mathcal S,\boxplus)$ is² computed as in $(\Bbb Z_p,+)$ when $x\ne\infty$.

Define scalar multiplication $\boxtimes: \Bbb Z\times\mathcal S\mapsto \mathcal S$ as:
$$k\boxtimes x=\begin{cases}
\infty&\text{when }k=0\\
(-k)\boxtimes(-x)&\text{when }k<0\\
\bigl((k-1)\boxtimes x\bigr)\boxplus x&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and for all $x$ in $\mathcal S$ and integers $k$, $k'$, it holds²:
$$\begin{align}
(k\boxtimes x)\,\boxplus\,(k'\boxtimes x)&=(k+k')\boxtimes x&\text{and}\\
k\boxtimes (k'\boxtimes x)&=(k\,k')\boxtimes x&\text{and}\\
k\boxtimes x&=(k\bmod m)\boxtimes x
\end{align}$$

---

For $x$ in $\{\infty\}\cup\Bbb Z_p$ define $\overline x=\begin{cases}
\infty&\text{when }x=\infty\\
\delta-x&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$.

Define $\hat{\mathcal S}$ as the set of $\overline x$ for all $x$ in $\mathcal S$. It holds $\hat{\mathcal S}=\mathcal S\iff l=-1$.

A function $f:\hat{\mathcal S}\times\hat{\mathcal S}\mapsto\hat{\mathcal S}$ compatible⁴ with the question's $f$ can²<sup>,</sup>⁵ now be defined as:
$$f(x,y)=\overline{-(\overline x\boxplus\overline y)}$$

The «restricted commutativity»³ property that $f\bigl(f(x,y),f(y',z)\bigr)=f\bigl(f(x,y'),f(y,z)\bigr)$ is a consequence of the associativity and commutativity of $\boxplus$ , and the fact for all $x$ in $\mathcal S$ it holds $\overline{(\overline x)}=x$.

Define:
$$\begin{align}
\hat s_0&=\overline a\\
\hat s_1&=\overline b\\
\hat s_n&=-(\hat s_{n-2}\boxplus\hat s_{n-1})\text{ when }n>1\\
\hat r_n&=-(\hat s_n\boxplus\hat s_0)\\
\end{align}$$
and for all $n$ it holds²: $\hat s_n=\overline{s_n}$ and $\hat r_n=\overline{r_n}$.

From this we can efficiently compute² integers $u_n$ and $v_n$ in $\Bbb Z_m$ such that:
$$\overline{r_n}=(u_n\boxtimes\overline a)\,\boxplus\,(v_n\boxtimes\overline b)$$

This allows² to solve for $a$ given $b$ and $r_n$, knowing parameters $p$, $z$, $n$. That's significantly easier than a discrete logarithm problem. When $\gcd(u_n,m)=1$, the unique solution is $$a=\overline{(u_n^{-1}\bmod m)\boxtimes(\overline{r_n}\,\boxplus\,(-v_n\boxtimes\overline b))}$$

---

Notes:

¹ : In particular, $\boxplus$ is² associative!

² : Proof is left as an exercise to the reader.

³ : See [document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OeKh_ZJF-i7_KzWFRv8jodk3YkXe2qyv) linked in the question.

⁴ : When $l\ne-1$ one of the input of $f$ can be excluded from $S$; assimilate it to $\infty$.

⁵ : $\delta$ and $\hat z$ are chosen such that $\overline{(x+y-1)^{-1}(-x\,y+x+y+z)}=-(\overline x\boxplus\overline y)$.

⁶ : This group has been identified [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3553280/35016), if not named.

Comment: As a side note: The function in the question doesn't have much in common with the function in the linked paper, except it is not assiosative. The function here is commutative.